# "non-standard" functions within dplyr summarise function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Say I have the following data frame:

```
    df<-data.frame(Name=c(rep("John",3),rep("Paul",2),rep("George",2),"Ringo"),
    Instrument=c("Guitar","Piano","Drums","Piano","Bass","Guitar","Sitar","Drums"))
    > df
        Name Instrument
    1   John     Guitar
    2   John      Piano
    3   John      Drums
    4   Paul      Piano
    5   Paul       Bass
    6 George     Guitar
    7 George      Sitar
    8  Ringo      Drums
```

What I'd like to do is group by Name and have the different instruments 
concatenated into a single string like:

```
    Name        Instruments
    1   John Guitar,Piano,Drums
    2   Paul         Piano,Bass
    3 George       Guitar,Sitar
    4  Ringo              Drums
```

I figured using group_by and paste within summarise ought to do the trick:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df <- df %>%
      group_by(Name) %>%
      summarise(Instruments = paste(Instrument,sep=","))
```

but instead, I get an "expecting a single value" error.  Is group_by only meant to work with numeric functions, and if so, does anyone know if there's a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Instruments = paste(Instrument ,collapse=" "))
```

note the `collapse`

Answer (score 2):

It may be also useful to `nest` the 'Instrument' as a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>%
   nest(Instrument)
```

---

If we need to `paste` them together, `toString` is a convenient wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=", ")`.

Comment: That actually makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do. You went beyond addressing the basic syntax problems and got right to the heart of the issue.